# How do I design the Schema for this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am developing a MERN app. I need to design schema for fairly simple mobile shop website.

Data should be in the format given below

```
    {
  [
    "IOS":[
      "Apple":[
        {
          "model":"Iphone6"
        },
        {
          "model":"Iphone7"
        }
      ]
    ],
    "Android":[
      "Samsung":[
        {
          "model":"S6"
        },
        {
          "model":"S7"
        }
      ],
      "OnePlus":[
        {
          "model":"oneplu6"
        },
        {
          "model":"onplus7"
        }
      ]
    ],
    "Windows":[
      "Nokia":[
        {
          "model":"Nokia 7.2"
        }
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
```

How do i design schema for this in mongo/mongoose?

Comment: It depends on your need. One solution could be to have a collection `Smartphones` and each document would be a phone with the fields `OS - Brand - Model`

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Weedoze . In the front end i want to hit url only once to get complete data iterating over it. Maybe i'm thinking with the wrong perception. Could you give a json format of your solution to visualise?

Comment: The data format you're suggesting is not a valid json ;) You cannot use Key/Value Pairs inside arrays. But apart from that you should provide some more information which information is required or what are the restrictions for the values

Comment: @relief.melone basic requirement is grouping the brand and model as mentioned in above mentioned json. under each OS platform i want to group the brands and their respective mobile models. So in frontend when i map the OS platform array, it should display all available brands in it(ex:IOS) and the corresponding mob models. then move on to the next OS platform(ex: Android) and its brand and models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the operating system and brand name as keys is not required, I have such a solution.

I would setup my schemas like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const operatingSystemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

const brandSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  model: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  operatingSystem: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "OperatingSystem"
  },
  brand: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Brand"
  }
});

module.exports = {
  OperatingSystem: mongoose.model("OperatingSystem", operatingSystemSchema),
  Brand: mongoose.model("Brand", brandSchema),
  Product: mongoose.model("Product", productSchema)
};
```

After inserting documents according to the schemas, we can use the following aggregate to group by Operating System and Brand:

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "operatingsystems",
      localField: "operatingSystem",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "operatingSystems"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "brands",
      localField: "brand",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "brands"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$operatingSystems"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$brands"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$$ROOT",
          {
            operatingSystem: "$operatingSystems.name",
            brand: "$brands.name"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      brands: 0,
      operatingSystems: 0
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "operatingSystem": "$operatingSystem",
        "brand": "$brand",

      },
      products: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$_id.operatingSystem",
      "data": {
        "$push": {
          "brand": "$_id.brand",
          "models": "$products.model"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "OS": "$_id",
      "_id": 0,
      "data": 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kYSZwnqghG6)

And sample route in express side:

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Product.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "operatingsystems",
        localField: "operatingSystem",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "operatingSystems"
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "brands",
        localField: "brand",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "brands"
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$operatingSystems"
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$brands"
    },
    {
      $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: {
          $mergeObjects: [
            "$$ROOT",
            {
              operatingSystem: "$operatingSystems.name",
              brand: "$brands.name"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        brands: 0,
        operatingSystems: 0
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          operatingSystem: "$operatingSystem",
          brand: "$brand"
        },
        products: {
          $push: "$$ROOT"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$_id.operatingSystem",
        data: {
          $push: {
            brand: "$_id.brand",
            models: "$products.model"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        OS: "$_id",
        _id: 0,
        data: 1
      }
    }
  ]);

  res.send(result);
});
```

The result will look like this:

```
[
  {
    "OS": "Windows",
    "data": [
      {
        "brand": "Nokia",
        "models": [
          "Nokia 7.2"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "OS": "Android",
    "data": [
      {
        "brand": "OnePlus",
        "models": [
          "oneplus7",
          "oneplu6"
        ]
      },
      {
        "brand": "Samsung",
        "models": [
          "S7",
          "S6"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "OS": "IOS",
    "data": [
      {
        "brand": "Apple",
        "models": [
          "Iphone7",
          "Iphone6"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```